# Writing text files in java

Tags: java, filewriter

So I know there are a lot of examples with writing textfiles, but I can't seem to get what is wrong with mine.

Here is the code I have so far

```
private void saveAddressBook() {
    try {  
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
        out.println(fullName);
        out.close();
       } catch(ValidationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```

I get an error on `out.println(fullName);` that says "fullName cannot be resolved to a variable"

Which makes no sense because I use it in other methods and classes. Not to mention it is public.

So what am I doing wrong?

Edit: fullName is declared right at the top of the class. I just didn't include it.

Comment: You havent declared `fullName` anywhere, from what I see

Comment: Looks like this variable is not a field of the class where you're defining this method.

Comment: please include the code where you actually define variable the fullName.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the variable fullName .
Try to declare and assign a value to the variable or give the String as the argument

```
out.println("my super string");
```

regards,

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have not defined the `fullName` variable.

Using `out.println("FirstName LastName");` will work just fine, but if you want to pass the `fullName` variable as an agument to `saveAddressBook` that would look like:

```
private void saveAddressBook(String fullName) {
    try {  
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");
        out.println(fullName);
        out.close();
       } catch(ValidationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
       }
}
```